# Backtesting GARCH model

Tags: r, garch, volatility-forecasting, error-message

Hi I am wondering wether the tgarch model is better for predicting volatility than regular garch
I built  a garch model in R and im trying to predict  future 1 day  volatility of this equity I am trying to backtest it and I'm getting this error.

```
library(quantmod)
library(rugarch)
getSymbols("SHOP.TO")
SHOP.TO_close<-SHOP.TO$CLOSErets = ROC(SHOP.TO_close)

tgarch = ugarchspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(1, 1)), 
                    variance.model = list(model = "gjrGARCH"),
                    distribution.model = "sstd")
garchroll<-ugarchroll(tgarch, data = rets,n.start =1076, 
                      refit.window="moving", refit.every =200)
```

The error I am getting is this

````
  wrong sign in 'by' argument
```
````

Comment: Is the missing " after SHOP.TO just a typo?

Comment: Yes it is just a typo ill fix that im sorry